# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URLSession'

Tags: swift, alamofire

I use Alamofire 4.0, Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.2 to request Http Api
I have url constant:

```
let weatherUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
```

And function:

```
func getWeatherData(url: String, parameters: [String : String])
    {
        Alamofire.Request(url, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
        {
                response in
        }

getWeatherData(url: weatherUrl, parameters: params)
```

And Xcode notify me:"Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URLSession'".

[image: Alamofire]

What is the problem?

Comment: shouldnt one of your parameters be [URL : String] or [String: URL] ? 
you also defined url:String , should it be url: URL

Comment: Which line? Which variable? Provide details in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy in line: Alamofire.Request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON. I have updated the image of the problem!

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The first argument in the call to `Alamofire.Request` needs to a `URL`, not a `String`.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you! I fixed it. :)

Comment: When I change the url parameter from the string to URLSession as suggested by xcode then the error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URLSession' in this line:
             getWeatherData (url: weatherUrl, parameters: params)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with as following code. Because URL is of type URLConvertible.

let url = URL(string: myURLString)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Request`, which is a type, and not `request`, which is the method you're looking for.